# Yii2 Call Console controller/action in backend controller

Tags: php, command-line, yii2, console, sitemap

I crited controller

> SiteMapController.php

with action

> index

in console folder of Yii2
 [image]

and I can run it from command  line.
[image]
But I need run it from controller of backend/controllers folder. it means I should run index action of controller SiteMapController.php from Yii2 backend controller action. Here my test code but it not works.
**Backend/controllers/BlogController.php**

```
private function runSiteMapGenerate(){
    $cr = new ConsoleRunner(['file' => '@console']);
    $cr->run('site-map');
}
```

I tried both scripts

```
"vova07/yii2-console-runner-extension": "*",
"tebazil/yii2-console-runner": "^0.0.0"
```

But its not help to run index

I have no more options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the yii directory using `chdir` and run the next `shell_exec`. Using this you can make it simple and no need to install any extensions.

```
chdir('../yiifolder'); //folder that contains yii
$output = shell_exec('php yii migrate');
var_dump($output);
```

This is tested on my server.

Output:

```
string 'Yii Migration Tool (based on Yii v2.0.6)

No new migration found. Your system is up-to-date.
' (length=93)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use [vova07/yii2-console-runner-extension](https://github.com/vova07/yii2-console-runner-extension) you need to set *file* to the path of the `yii` script which is usually located in the root folder - you don't specify the console directory here. So it is very likely that you create the object this way:

```
// assuming you have file 'yii' in the root directory:
$cr = new ConsoleRunner(['file' => '@app/yii']);
```

Then the actual call should work:

```
// assuming that 'index' is the default action
$cr->run('site-map');
// or
$cr->run('site-map/index');
```

Info: if a console command should be executed you actually call `yii` with some parameters for the command. You don't call the command directly. `yii` starts a console application. Just have a look into this file. It is part of the [yii2-app-advanced](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced) (present if the `init` script was executed on setup) and [yii2-app-basic](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic) project templates.